# Search column for string and hide row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If number in column A is found in the string in column B, then hide the entire corresponding row. The list is pretty long, the data looks something like this :

```
Column A      Column B
1234          3456/4532
5678          3456/333/1234
2222          3456/6666
```

Row 2 should get hidden. 
 Can't seem to figure it out.

```
function test()
{
   var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); // read all data in the sheet
   for(n=0;n<data.length;++n) // iterate row by row and examine data
   { 
     if(data[n][0].toString().match(data[n][1])==data[n][1])
     { 
       sh.hideRows(n);
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
  {
    for(var j=0; j<data.length; j++)
    {
      if(data[j][1].toString().indexOf(data[i][0]) >= 0)
      {
        sh.hideRows(j+1);
      }
    }
  }
```

**One thing to note**:

The variable 'sh' (i.e. `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`) will store sheet in 'sh' with starting index (1,1), which is the A1 cell, whereas 'data' variable will store the spreadsheet as 2D array inside 'data' and it will consider A1 as (0,0).

So, if you use `sh.hideRows()`, you should take 2nd row of sheet as index '2' and not '1'. That's why I have used 'j+1'.

Comment: Thanks! Worked great!

Comment: You can accept it as an answer if it solves your question. :)